# python doctest from a separate file + location

Tags: python, doctest

I have a directory structure like this:

```
|-root
  |-app
    program.py
    tests.txt
  |-tests
    runTests.py
```

My tests.txt file contains all the doctests on my program.py code. It calls

```
from program import *
```

and then it makes all the doctest calls.
My runTests.py file has this code:

```
import doctest
doctest.testfile("app/tests.txt")
```

In the command line I then call:

```
python runTests.py
```

and it does indeed find the tests.txt file and reads it successfully but it does not find the module "program" which I am trying to import. What am I doing wrong? How can I have them in separate directories and still be able to run the tests?

Thanks

Comment: Why not make `tests.txt` a *Python file*?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to do this:

1. You can add it the `sys.path` in `runTests.py`: `import sys; sys.path.append('app')`
   The same can be achieved with the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`.
2. You can turn the folder into a package by adding a file `__init__.py` and importing `from app.program import *` in `tests.txt`.

Reminder: The main premise of `doctest` is that the method/function documentation (what you get when you look at the `__doc__` property) explains what it does *and* gives examples (the tests).

Doctest then finds such code and executes it, making sure that the examples in the documentation are actually working.

If you move the tests out, then you're taking away a major source of information from the user of your code. I guess it might make sense if you have extensive documentation outside of the source code or if you have many additional tests (you want to give users a few examples, not all 500 unit tests which drive code coverage to 100%).

That said, to fix the issue, you need to make the import work. The folder `app` doesn't magically appear in the search path for modules. You have to tell Python that this is in fact a place where it should look.

Comment: It might not be python code, just text with doctest tests interspersed.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thank you for your detailed response. I thought having the doctests separately is good design for bigger programs. Here is from the python manual: https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#simple-usage-checking-examples-in-a-text-file 
You are probably right about the .txt, but it's not really code, it's doctest stuff. Again, the link above also uses an example.txt file to run the tests

Comment: @user3578788: Hm. I stand corrected :-) I've reworded my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @AaronDigulla. I'm almost there. I did what you said, turned it into a module with the __init__.py file and it works if the runTests.py is in the root dir and has to go into the app dir to load the module. If however I place it inside the test dir and it has to first go up one level before going into the app it gives me an error saying "ImportError: No module named app.program". I know it finds the file because later on it also gives an error saying that it can't find a function I have inside the program.py. The file was opened, it's the module loading that failed. Any ideas?

Comment: Start the test from the root folder: `python test/runTests.py`.